How to Install Ubuntu(WSL) in Windows 11 pro?
I want to know detailed procedure of installing Ubuntu in Windows 11pro.Do installing Ubuntu in Windows 11pro and Windows 11 follow same procedure

We are not that kind of site. If you need a how to google has all the answers to that. Besides that: this is a WINDOWS question: how to install software in Windows.Likely you install it like any other software on Windows?!?! AskUbuntu starts after that part is done and you need an answer to a problem you face (like an error or a command).

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
